# Theano AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'relu'

Tags: python, bash, pip, theano

I want to use `theano.tensor.nnet.relu`, but I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'relu'
```

I have already updated theano via `sudo pip install --upgrade theano` command as described in [theano's documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#updating-theano), also i've tried `sudo pip install --upgrade --no-deps theano`. Neither worked, I still get the same error.

I was trying to do `theano -v` to confirm that I have installed the latest version but then I get the following error: `-bash: theano: command not found`

So my two questions here are:

- How can I see theano's version?
- Am I doing something wrong when updating theano? How can I solve the error first mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[relu](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/nnet.html?highlight=relu#theano.tensor.nnet.relu) is available for **theano >=  0.7.1**. My guess is that pip linked to `theano==0.7`.

You can check theano version with `pip freeze`:

```
pip freeze | grep Theano
```

So you have to install latest `theano` with pointing pip to theano git repo :

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
```

Also note that relu is function and **not module**, so to access it you have to use one of imports below:

```
from theano.tensor.nnet import relu # access `relu` as is ..
import theano.tensor.nnet as theano_nnet #access `relu` as `theano_nnet.relu`
```

Answer (score 1):

The `theano.tensor.nnet` module only supports `relu` in the most recent versions. In order to use it, you need to install the bleeding edge version from github or wait until the next release.

Alternatively, you can implement it like this:

```
def relu(x):
    return T.maximum(x, 0.)
```

This may not be inplace but it gives you the result and the gradient.

Answer (score 1):

1. to see theano version you can run the following code:

   ```
   import theano
   print theano.__version__
   ```
2. You should follow the instructions from [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions) to get the bleeding edge version

Actually relu function is simple to code, you can create your own relu function, like eickenberg's answer, or like `theano.tensor.nnet` style:

```
    def relu(x):   
       return 0.5 * (x + abs(x))
```

Comment: True, good point: The sum of `x` and `abs(x)` was shown to be faster at some point and also made its way into lasagne, at least at the beginning.